# LINQ to SQL search a word from table

Tags: c#

Need a help to resolve this question.

I have a table name `Book` on which there is a requirement :-

Create a .NET Web site that displays the `Book`s for sale using `GridView` and following these constraints

1. Use the Linq to SQL provider
2. use Linq for your queries
3. importantly, make sure your Linq query does not show the price to those who view the site
4. Add a search box to your website. With it, the user can search for a `Book` by title.

So far I have worked on this...need to add search box and search for a `Book` by `Title`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BookDataContext db = new BookDataContext();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var query = from m in db.Books
                    select new { BookName = m.Name, Title = m.Title };

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: look up `Where` clauses. use google.

Comment: How **Where** clause will help to search the string from table @Dleh Can you please explain more about it

Answer (score 0):

The query is as simple as this

```
var query = from book in db.Books
            where book.Title.Contains(txtSearch.Text)
            select new { BookName = book.Name, Title = book.Title };
```

The txtSearch is the name of the search textbox in your page.

More LINQ examples here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: How to achieve this "Add a search box to your website. With it, the user can search for a Book by title"